# How can i clear the all contents of the cell data in every row in my tableview in JAVA FX

Tags: java, javafx

I am finding hard to clear the table contents in my table. I have tried this code.

```
for ( int i = 0; i<resultTable.getItems().size(); i++) {
    resultTable.getItems().clear();
}
```

To clarify my question, the problem I am having is that i want to delete the values in my table. This was the first code i used;

```
public void removeRow(){
    allFiles = table.getItems(); fileSelected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems(); 
    fileSelected.forEach(allFiles :: remove); 
}
```

But it only removes a particular selected row. I want to clear all the rows and leave the table empty at once, without having to select any row. I tried to use this code;

```
public void removeAllRows(){
    for ( int i = 0; i<resultTable.getItems().size(); i++) {
        resultTable.getItems().clear(); 
    } 
}
```

but it does not clear all the rows in the table

My plan is to use this method as an action for a button.
e.g

```
Button btn = new ("Clear Table");
btn..setOnAction(e->{removeAllRows();});
```

When this button is clicked, it should delete all rows in the table at once.

Comment: `resultTable.getItems().clear();` is all you need.

Comment: I have already done that but it only removes only the first row.

Comment: Thanks.. user7144965..It was a debugging issue.

Comment: You may have to do `resultTable.refresh()` after.

Comment: @trilogy _You may have to do resultTable.refresh()_ not if the all is wired as it should (except in extremely rare corner cases which most certainly is not the case here ;).

Answer (score 18):

`tableView.getItems().clear()`

Will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following: Name "tableView" to whatever your `FXMLtable` is called

```
for ( int i = 0; i<tableView.getItems().size(); i++) {
    tableView.getItems().clear();
}
```

Comment: tableView.getItems().clear() clears all TableView data. No need to loop it.

Answer (score 1):

To entirely clear/reset the table (including header), I used this

```
    tableView.getColumns().clear();
    tableView.getItems().clear();
```

might help somebody